# Points on circle graph (AMC 10A 2015 #12)

Tags: contest-math, coordinate-systems

I'm stumped by the following question:

**Points $(\sqrt{\pi}, a)$ and $(\sqrt{\pi}, b)$ are distinct points on the graph of $y^2+x^4=2x^2y+1$. What is $|a-b|$?**

### Method

See, my train of thought followed as such:

First of all, we see that the two points have the same x value, and thus they probably lie on the circumference of a circle.

$y^{ 2 }+x^{ 4 }=2x^{ 2 }y+1$

$z = { x }^{ 2 }$

$y^{ 2 }-2zy+z^{ 2 }=1$

This simplifies to:
${ (y-z) }^{ 2 }=1$

$y=1+z$

We remember that x = $\sqrt { \pi  } $, and since $z={ x }^{ 2 }$, $z=\pi $, y = $1+\pi $. This is where I realized I went wrong somewhere, since |a-b| = 0 at this point. I really have **no idea how to proceed at this point**, as I believed the problem originally required basic algebraic manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a mistake when you concluded that $(y-z)^2=1 \implies y-z=1$. In fact, $$(y-z)^2=1 \implies y-z=\pm1 \implies y=z\pm 1.$$
Finally, $|a-b|=|z+1-(z-1)|=2$.

Comment: What a foolish mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

we have $$x^4-2x^2y+y^2=1$$ or
$$(x^2-y)^2=1$$
plugging the coordinates we get
$$\pi-a)^2=1$$
and
$$(\pi-b)^2=1$$